# MYSQL No suitable driver found

Tags: mysql, mariadb

actualmente uso Intellij, resulta que  estoy intentando conectar a una base de datos MySQL, pero tras  añadidir la libreria y usar una clase conexión (la cual funciona perfectamente con el driver de MariaDB) me encuentro con el error plasmado en el título de la pregunta

```
public void conectar() {
        try {
            conexion = DriverManager.getConnection(url, usuario, contraseña);
            if (conexion != null) { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Conexión establecida a : \n" + url,  "ACDA2", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                stm = conexion.createStatement();//crea un objeto que permite enviar instrucciones a la base de datos
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Conexión fallida a : \n " + url, "", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al cargar el driver", "", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estos son los valores que mando a mi clase conexión

```
   c= new conexion("jdbc:mysql://", "127.0.0.1/", "root", "", "sanciones");
   c.conectar();
```

Y a continuación os detallo el constructor de la clase conexión

```
 public conexion(String driver,String host, String usuario, String 
 contraseña, String baseDatos) {
    this.usuario = usuario;
    this.contraseña = contraseña;
    this.baseDatos = baseDatos;
    this.driver = driver;
    this.host = host;
    this.url = driver + this.host  + this.baseDatos;
}
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN DE ESTADO**

He conseguido conectarme a MySQL situando el Class.forName antes de conectar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tras leer los manuales de MySQL me surge la siguiente duda, desde el conector 4.0 no es necesario usar el `Class.ForName` para cargar la librería puesto que automatizaría el proceso, entonces....¿Por que funciona si situo esa linea antes de conectar y despues no? He probado a crear un proyecto en el que solo conecta con una sola línea (Sin hacer uso de Class.ForName), y no conecta (No driver found) Os recuerdo que uso java 1.8 y el conector 5.1.5, también he probado la conexión en NetBeans y Eclipse y tampoco funciona sin el `Class.ForName`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

SOLUCIÓN

Las versiones del driver com.mysql.jdbc_5.1.5 no permiten la carga implicita del driver debido a la carencia de la subcarpeta Services en META-INF y su correspondiente contenido, aunque sea JDBC4 y en los manuales de mysql se diga que es posible ,no lo es, almenos con esta versión específica, saludos

Comment: El `Class.forName()` no es necesario desde hace muchos años, y no estás poniendo la URL que usas...

Comment: Gracias, recién edite el post

Comment: ¿Qué jars tienes en tu librería?

Comment: com.mysql.jdbc_5.1.5

Comment: En librerías externas solo ese amigo

Comment: No estoy familiarizado con IntelliJ, pero no creo que ése sea el nombre del jar sino de una agrupación de jars usada internamente por intellij. Expande el elemento `com.mysql.jdbc_5.1.5`

Comment: Como ya ha comentado alguno, `Class.forName` hace tiempo que no es necesario. A tu cadena de conexión le faltan cosas, por ejemplo, no indicas el puerto donde corre tu BD. Prueba algo como esto: **`Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/DB?user=root&password=myPassword");`** cambiando lo que haya que cambiar según tu contexto. Queda claro que, debes verificar si JDBC está agregado correctamente a  tu proyecto y que tienes la BD funcionando correctamente. [Revisa la doc](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/about-mariadb-connector-j/) si tienes más dudas.

Comment: El elemento contiene las siguientes carpetas : com.mysql.jdbc / META-INF / org.gjt.mm.mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

comprueba que dentro de tu carpeta `META-INF` del driver se encuentra una carpeta llamada `services` la cual debe contener un documento que tenga `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` si no tienes esta carpeta de `services` seria problema del Driver que te has descargado,puesto que el ClassLoader no carga la clase automáticamente y debes usar el `Class.ForName()` para cargarlo explicita-mente.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, despues de horas buscando información desde diferentes fuentes, no pensaba encontrar la respuesta en esta pequeña pero agradable comunidad, saludos :D