# Conectar base de datos con java (connector j)

Tags: java, mysql, mysqlconnector

Estoy intentado conectar la base de datos en java pero me sale un error que nunca antes me apareció

```
Error Database
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:390)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:381)
    at Main.main(Main.java:30)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.sql.Connection.close()" because "Main.conn" is null
    at Main.main(Main.java:40)
```

Este es el codigo que estoy usando:

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

private static final String DB_SERVER = "localhost";
private static final int DB_PORT = 3306;
private static final String DB_NAME = "restaurant";
private static final String DB_USER = "root";
private static final String DB_PASS = "";

private static Connection conn;


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

   try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + DB_SERVER + ":" + DB_PORT + "/" + DB_NAME;
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error Database");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    conn.close();
}
//...Otras funciones
}
```

La base de datos la tengo desde xampp
[image: Imagen bd]

[image: Puerto y password]

Tengo abierta la base de datos desde el navegador por lo que se debería poder conectar al igual que puede acceder desde web. Nunca antes me salio este tipo de error y eso que ya había intentado conectar a la base de datos antes

Ayer hice la conexión bien pero hoy me salta ese error, alguna idea de a que se debe?

Comment: Pues moviste el jar del driver, cambiaste la forma como declaras el classpath y no inlcuye el driver o algo hizo que el driver ya no esté disponible al ejecutar

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [MYSQL No suitable driver found](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/212454/mysql-no-suitable-driver-found)

Comment: Le echaré in vistazo, gracias

Comment: No se usa `Class.forName` desde JDBC 4. Ignoro cuál sea tu versión de JDBC, si es 4 o superior intenta con `DriverManager.getConnection()` directamente, como muestra el segundo bloque de código en el [Manual de Referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html). Debes asegurarte de que tienes JDBC añadido correctamente en tu proyecto.

Comment: Tiene pinta de que va a ser eso, probaré